# Server doesn't receive client Object java

Tags: java, server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

i have a server that work if change String with clients. Now,i want to use Object instead of String but the server doesn't receive anything and get stugged before the sout like the client doesn't sand anything...So, the problem is on the client or on the server?? Message is a class with interface Serializable and i called input before output in server and output before input in client.

Server:

```
public class ControllerServer {
   @FXML
   public ListView<Log> log_list;
   @FXML
   public MenuItem disconnect_button;
   @FXML
   public MenuItem connect_button;

   boolean connection = true;
   DataModel model;
   ObservableList<Log> list;
   Connection conn = new Connection();
   @FXML
   public void initialize() throws TransformerConfigurationException {
      if (this.model != null) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
      }
      model = new DataModel();

      list = model.getLogList();
      log_list.setItems(list);


      log_list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,oldLog,newLog) -> model.setCurrentLog(newLog));

      model.currentEmailProperty().addListener((obs, oldLog, newLog) -> {
         if (newLog == null) {
            log_list.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

         } else {
            log_list.getSelectionModel().select(newLog);
         }
      });

      log_list.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Log>() {
         @Override
         public void updateItem(Log message, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(message, empty);
            if (empty) {
               setText(null);
            } else {
               setText(message.getContent());
            }
         }
      });
      conn.start();


   }

   public void disconnect(ActionEvent actionEvent)  {
      if(connection){
         connection = false;
         conn.cancel();
         if(disconnect_button!=null)disconnect_button.setVisible(false);
         if(connect_button!=null)connect_button.setVisible(true);
      }else System.out.println("The server is closed!");

   }

   public void connect(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      if(!connection){
         conn.restart();
         connection = true;
         if(disconnect_button!=null)disconnect_button.setVisible(true);
         if(connect_button!=null)connect_button.setVisible(false);
      }
      else System.out.println("Already connected");
   }


   public class Connection extends Service<Void>{
      ServerSocket s;
      ExecutorService listeners = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      ArrayList<Socket> incomings_connection = new ArrayList<>();

      int id=1;
      @Override
      protected Task<Void> createTask() {
         return new Task<>() {
         @Override
         protected Void call() {
            System.out.println("Server Attivo");
               try {
                  s = new ServerSocket(8189);
                  while (!isCancelled()) {
                     Thread.sleep(500);
                     System.out.println("In attesa di connessione....");
                     Socket incoming = s.accept();
                     incomings_connection.add(incoming);
                     Task<Void> listener = new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {
                           int id_task = id;
                           System.out.println("Connessione accettata! Client: "+id_task);

                           ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
                           ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());

                           Message request;
                           while (!isCancelled()){
                              Object obj = inStream.readObject();
                              try{
                                 request = (Message)obj;
                                 System.out.println("Arrivato: "+request.getMessage()+"  e: "+request.getAction());
                              }catch (ClassCastException e){
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                              }

                           }
                              return null;
                        }
                     };
                     listeners.submit(listener);
                     id++;
                  }
               }catch (SocketException ex){
                  System.out.println("Listener chiuso!");
               }
               catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            return null;
         }

            @Override
            protected void cancelled() {
               System.out.println("Closing server....");
               System.out.println("Done!");
                  try {
                     s.close();
                     try {
                        System.out.println("Connessioni chiuse: "+incomings_connection.size());
                        for(Socket conn: incomings_connection){
                           conn.close();
                        }
                     }catch (NullPointerException EX){
                        System.out.println("Non è stata stabilita nessuna connesione client prima della chiusura!");
                     }
                     model.closeLog();
                  }
                  catch (NullPointerException EX){
                     System.out.println("Server non inizializzato correttamente");
                  }
                  catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }

               super.cancelled();
            }

         };
      }

      private String login(String email) {
         String response = null;
         try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Huawei\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Università\\prog3\\Progetto\\Server\\src\\main\\resources\\Utenti\\"+email+"\\Info.txt"));
            response = reader.readLine();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            response = "Error: user inesistente";
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return response;
      }
   }
}
```

Client

```
public class ControllerClient {

    Log log = new Log();
    Connection conn;
    @FXML
    public TextField email;
    @FXML
    public Button submit_button;
    @FXML
    public Label ConnectionFailureText;
    @FXML
    public Button try_connect;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() {
        conn = new Connection(log);
        conn.start();
    }

    public void re_connect(ActionEvent event){

    }

    public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(this.conn.isRunning()){
            if (email.getText()!=null && email.getText()!="" ){
                log.put(new Message("login",email.getText()));
            }else System.out.println("Inserisci la mail!");
        }
        else System.out.println("Connessione chiusa!");
    }

     class Connection extends Service<Void> {
        Log log;Socket s;
        public Connection(Log item){
            log = item;
        }
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        String nomeHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
                        s = new Socket(nomeHost, 8189);
                        System.out.println("Ho aperto il socket verso il server");
                        try{

                            ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                            System.out.println("Sto per ricevere dati dal socket server!");

                            Message message = null;

                            while (!isCancelled())  {
                                message = log.get();
                                if(message!=null){
                                    System.out.println("message: "+message.getMessage() + "  " +message.getAction());
                                    outStream.writeObject(message);
                                }

                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("Connessione col server interrotta!");
                            s.close();conn.cancel();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Errore di connessione!");

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

         @Override
         protected void cancelled() {
             System.out.println("Connessione chiusa");
             super.cancelled();
         }
     }
}

class Log {
    private boolean available = false;
    private Message message = null;

    public synchronized Message get(){
        while (!available) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        /* fondamentale notifyAll(), anziché notify(), per prevenire deadlock */
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(Message value) {
        while (available) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        message = value;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

Message:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private String action;
    private String message;
    private Email email;

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Message(String action, String message){
        this.action=action;
        this.message=message;
    }
    public Message(String action, String message, Email email){
        this.action=action;
        this.message=message;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post complete classes? The Server class is not complete.

Comment: Try calling `flush()` after `writeObject`. And consider *always* closing resources after use, not only in the exceptional case.

Comment: i loaded full server @hfontanez

Comment: The server is stucked in `Object obj = inStream.readObject();`, how can i call flush? @Holger

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello where is the `Task` class defined? I can't import it.

Comment: in the class of GUI, i'll post it

Comment: Both classes are called `Connection`? You really need to post more complete code. Maybe Holger's advice will work, but I can't run your code because it is not complete.

Comment: i'm going to post the enteir post...i thought it was too much

Comment: but where i have to do the flush? cause inStream.flush() doesn't work

Comment: Connection is the name class of both, Server and Client, but thy run on different java application project

Comment: "calling `flush()` after `writeObject`" means that the code calling `writeObject` should do that, right afterwards. That's the client in the code you've posted.

Comment: sorry, i tried on client after readObject...i'm going to try now

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: i think the problem is the object that i want to send

Comment: Message is equals for both, it's a wrong implementation?

Comment: The question is, how can i use Message class implemented in Client on Server?How can i import it? Cause, now it's just a copy of the class implemented on Client...maybe is required the same class

Comment: Since both programs run in their own environments, it’s always effectively a copy. There’s no such thing as “the same class” here. There are always two distinct classes generated from the same byte sequence. Did you verify that the client truly wrote an object and returned from `flush()`?

Comment: i solved  opening the entire project and import on server the client class